# Twitter Bootstrap nav tabs conflict with KnockoutJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem with ["Basic Tabs"](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs). I'm rendering the tabs in a View in MVC and then I have bunch of KnockoutJS code in three different Partial Views.

My problem is that Knockout is conflicting with other Knockout code because each Partial View creates a MVVM and applies bindings.

Is there some way I can skip rendering the DIV (with the Partial Views) until the relevant tab is pressed?

Here is my code for the regular View:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#attributes">Attributes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#interestgroups">Interest groups</a></li>
    <li><a href="#categories">Categories</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="attributes" class="tab-pane active">
        @Html.Partial("_AttributesPartial")
    </div>
    <div id="interestgroups" class="tab-pane">
        @Html.Partial("_InterestGroupsPartial")
    </div>
    <div id="categories" class="tab-pane">
        @Html.Partial("_InterestGroupCategoriesPartial")
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    });

    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: We need to see your KO code as well because that's where the problem lies. Are you keeping all of the scripts in their own views? Also, are the different partials meant to interact with each other? In other words, do changes one tab affect another?

Comment: The problem is I have KO code in each partial view, with ko.applyBindings() in each one. This is conflicting because when I run the view (code above) it renders EVERYTHING. I want to render content in tabs on demand, so when I press "Attributes" _AttributesPartial is loaded but no other partial view. So when I click "Interest groups" tab _InterestGroupsPartial is rendered but no other partial view. Get the idea? So instead of $(this).tab('show') I need something like: $(this).tab('render');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to watch out for would be calling ko.applyBindings more than once with only one argument.

For instance—if you have more than one view model on a page (I'm inferring from your question), then you need to scope it, by passing in the container element as the second argument.

Per your comment, if you want to lazy load the stuff you just have to listen for the 'shown' event.

(this is pseudocode, you'll have to fill in the details)

```
$('#attributes').on('shown', function (e) {
   initKOView(e.target);  // some logic to determine which viewModel to bind to.
})

function initKOView(target) {
   $(target).load('controller/_RenderPartial?path=' + target, function(data) {
      $(this).html(data);
      // Once the data comes back, apply your bindings and make sure to scope it.
      ko.applyBindings(viewModels[target], this);
   })
}
```

As discussed here, there is not really a way to teardown whole sets of bindings currently - so you'll still want to scope your view model.

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/41#issuecomment-749171

Then in your controller, you'll want to add a `PartialViewResult`

```
public PartialViewResult _RenderPartial(string path)
{
    return PartialView(path);
}
```

Of course, you can have a separate controller action for each one too, and skip the parameterized loading. Also, you'll want to nix all of the `@Html.Partial()` stuff out of your master view too.

Comment: This would work if I didn't have more code that launches. Like getJSON AJAX call.